# Location of ag-grid-enterprise typings when using specific modules?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

To reduce the code size of my Angular app I followed the guide at [link](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/modules/) to load only the specific modules needed.
An example of importing types is provided in AG Grid docs:

```
import { ColumnApi, GridApi } from "@ag-grid-community/core";
import { LicenseManager } from "@ag-grid-enterprise/core";
```

I am finding that various types that are specific to Enterprise features (e.g. IServerSideDatasource) are only available to import from "@ag-grid-community/core" and not from "@ag-grid-enterprise/core", which seems counterintuitive - am I missing something? Don't want to import the wrong typings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though this can be confusing, `IServerSideDatasource` is an interface and in the source code, all interfaces are declared inside [community-module/core](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/tree/latest/community-modules/core/src/ts/interfaces). The usage of this interface can be observed in [Server Side Row Model enterprise feature](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/latest/enterprise-modules/server-side-row-model/src/serverSideRowModel/serverSideRowModel.ts) which is part of the enterprise-module.

You can also see that the `IServerSideDatasource` type is being used in some core properties of grid like the [gridOptions](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/latest/community-modules/core/src/ts/entities/gridOptions.ts) & [gridOptionsWrapper](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/latest/community-modules/core/src/ts/gridOptionsWrapper.ts) which are part of `@ag-grid-community/core`.

There are not much explanations out there to get a straight forward answer, however we can see that the particular interface is common to both community and enterprise modules. Also, it could be due to maintaining a project structure where all interfaces & core types are part of the community-module/core.